# File persistently cached in Yii despite overwrite

Tags: caching, yii, yii-components

I have this weird problem with one of our file. It's named Setup.php and stored under protected/components/

This file is mainly for emails, header, footer generating functions etc. We found out few days back that when we changed the footer layout in this file, the old footer would still show, despite doing a lot of debugging and edits (even removing the footer function itself), it still shows the old one. This is a shocker. I'm aware of cache issues but does Yii cache the whole PHP file? Is this even possible? We are positive the footer used the same function from the same file.

I'm again having this issue with another function in the same file. Determined it's a problem with the component file and Yii, I would like to seek assistance from the Yii users.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your view never uses that file for rendering the footer.

Comment: @nterms That's what I thought too, but I'm 100% sure it's using the same function only that I think it's using a cached version of it which is why it never renders the updated one.